# How to handle authorize.net callback using GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I have been building a web app using Google Web Toolkit on the Google App Engine platform.
Now my client has requested that I add payment processing. I started implementing authorize.net but I am bumping my head against the handling of the callback url using GWT.

How can I set up a redirection url that receives the posted data from authorize.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT your callback URL should have nothing to do with GWT. It should map to a callback processing servlet which should modify the session state of the user who initiated the transaction. Your GWT app could in the meanwhile be polling the server for a change in user session state signifying that the transaction is successful (or not).

Comment: Thank you! I was scatching my head on how to return control to my GWT app since that is inherently just a single monolithic web page. Was trying to come up with all kinds of dirty tricks involving iframes. Sometimes the elegant and obvious escapes us. May be time for a vacation :-)